# How to make an IN query in Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene.net

I have added one field `ID` with `STORE NO` and `NOT ANALYZED` in `index.ID` field will contain only unique ids.

I want to use an `IN` query. E.g. if I want only documents with ids 1, 2, 3, 4 by searching in index, I have tried QueryParser separating ids with space 1 2 3 4.

It does give me. But is there any other method which is more fast and feasible?

Comment: can you put the query you are trying to build

Comment: QueryParser par=new QueryParser(version.30,"Id",new Standardanalyzer(version.30));Query qry=par.parser("1 2 3 4");searcher.search(qry,reader.maxdoc);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405203/how-to-query-for-terms-in-a-collection-using-lucene-net-similar-to-sqls-in-ope) there some other methods to implement an `IN` operator.

By default, all terms passed to `Lucene.Net` (space-separated terms) are ORed. Executing,

```
Id: 1 2 3 4
```

Will return all documents that match ANY of the ids passed.

You can use something like,

```
var collection = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
var query = new QueryParser(version, propertyName, analyzer)
    .Parse(string.Join(" ", collection));
```

to pass a list of terms to Lucene.Net as an `IN` operator.