# How to implement SQL SERVER NOT IN clause with Lucene

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

How to implement "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID NOT IN(4,5,6)" in Lucene

Comment: can you post what your have already tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405203/how-to-query-for-terms-in-a-collection-using-lucene-net-similar-to-sqls-in-ope)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
NOT(ID:(4 OR 5 OR 6)) AND *:*
```

The Lucene QueryParser will generate a query for that expression that gives similar results to the SQL query you gave.  The AND *:* is necessary since Lucene won't give any results back for a purely negative query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using just the Lucene Query-based objects. You'd use `MUST_NOT`/`-` in conjunction with a [MatchAllDocsQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html). (See the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089831/lucene-query-fails-with-mixed-must-must-not) for more info on why a MatchAllDocsQuery is needed.)

Your query would then look something like this:
`*:* -ID:4 -ID:5 -ID:6`